# SQL Server Express triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server

My company is using an inventory tracking system called LanSweeper to keep track of inventory. It uses SQL Server Express to store the data. The software does not log changes made to the database... like say someone deleted a laptop that they didn't want anyone to notice missing... I am familiar with SQLite enough to grasp the syntax, but am learning there are quite a few differences between all the flavors of SQL. Is there any way to create triggers on the database directly that would allow an output to a `.txt` file somewhere?

Comment: You don't want to output to a text file. Sorry, let me rephrase: "You might want to output to a text file, but you shouldn't. Write to another table instead".

Comment: I said txt file because i was looking for a quick easy fix? I realize writing to another table is ideal, and if this were sqlite i would love to do that, because throwing a java application to view and track the data in this table is something i could do in just a few minutes. But assuming another table is the only option how could i go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are tricky business so please spend time learning about them. They're not as simple as they appear on the surface (e.g. you **must** cater for when *multiple* updates are made in a single transaction)

You can start your reading in the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Use triggers to write changes to tables, not to text files. Not going to go in to a lot of detail here as it is a whole other discussion but trust me, you don't want triggers writing to files.

So general approach time:

1. Create an audit table (it should look very much like the base table but you'll likely want some additional columns like: "WhoIsMessingWithMyData" and "WhenWereTheyPrattingAround" <- names are obviously tongue in cheek here.
2. Write a trigger on your source table to write changes to the audit table.
3. ...
4. Profit!

---

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_audit (
    nice         char(1)
  , things       int
  , modified_by  sysname  NOT NULL DEFAULT SUser_SName() --This depends on your authentication method
  , when_changed datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT Current_Timestamp
);

CREATE TRIGGER your_table_audit_trigger
  ON your_table
AFTER DELETE
  AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO your_table_audit (nice, things)
  SELECT nice
       , things
  FROM   deleted
END
;
```

Comment: I really appreciate the example, I had a very basic trigger i wanted to try...how do i interface sql express though? Its a server edition right? I have a program called SQL Offline that allows me to view the tables but i cannot actually run queries against the tables.

Comment: You haven't said what version (year) of SQL Server you are using, but you're looking for a product called **SQL Server Management Studio Express**

Comment: That's the thing, i'm not using sql server. This database is stored locally within the program. Its hosted using IIS Express. I don't have any experience with SQL server...not to say i cant learn, but in my experience with sqlite there are 3rd party apps that i could just load a db file into, edit and put it back when im done. There is nothing like this for sql express? Im assuming sql server management studio express is a "plug-in" of sorts for sql server?

Comment: SSMS is a standalone application that can connect to SQL Server databases.

Answer (score 0):

[LanSweeper](http://www.lansweeper.com/) apparently does offer an Audit trail, I would be a poorly designed inventory system that allowed devices to be removed without notice.

From the website:

"Lansweeper cannot only detect all hardware devices in your computers but with its change tracking it can find out when a device was changed or removed. Not only does Lansweeper scans windows devices, it also gathers details about all other IP enabled devices on your network from the network discovery scan. (Linux, Printers, Routers, ...)"

Maybe that feature is currently disabled?
Sorry, if this seems Snarky, Just trying to help you avoid re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: the changes it is referring to is changes made by the software itself. Lansweeper performs a network discovery and it tracks when the software finds the asset, when something like an ip changes and things like that. I thought it would be a very poor design if it didnt track this as well. So i emailed them and they confirmed that there while this feature is on their "wishlist" it is not a current functionality of the software.